# Как запустить из PHP консольную программу и интерактивно взаимодействовать с ней, посылая запросы в ответ на приглашение?

Tags: php

Есть скомпилированная программа myprog в Ubuntu. На ввод она получает текстовую строку и символ конца строки, на вывод посылает преобразованную строку, далее ждет очередную строку.

Необходимо запустить эту внешнюю программу из PHP таким образом, чтобы она висела в памяти до завершения скрипта. Отправлять ей строки и получать обратно результаты в цикле.
Как это можно реализовать?

Вариант многократным запуском программы в самом цикле - не подходит.

Нужно что-то вроде:

```
$pid = openExtProg('myprog');

for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++) {
    echo sendStr($pid, "строка $i\n");
}

closeExtProg($pid);
```

Comment: Смотреть в сторону proc_open()

Comment: собственно [тут пример№1](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php) наверное как раз описывает вашу задачу

Comment: пробовал этот пример №1. Для первой итерации цикла работает. На второй итерации завершается ошибкой  "supplied resource is not a valid stream resource". Я так понял дело тут  в fclose. Пробовал закомментировать их - скрипт просто зависает на echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);. Посылал также строку с "\n" и c "\r\n" - также висит. Не совсем понятно, для чего делать fclose.

Comment: заменил stream_get_contents() на fread($pipes[1], 1024). Вроде работает.